# Export Acumatica Report / Find Report Name

Tags: acumatica

Why does Acumatica Cloud sometimes export reports as a .rpx and sometimes not? I'm trying to locate the name of this report to edit in design viewer, which cannot be found. Ultimately, I'm trying to edit the design of the report as well as change the parameter for start date and end date. The report is currently including year-to-date data, but I would like it to only show a selected month of data. The Start Period / End Period DEFAULT DATA SOURCE SETTINGS are not working.

I'm unable to download the .rpx file. It instead opens the following window...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Acumatica doesn't export report as '.rps' file, it exports them as '.rpx' files.
Both format are plain text and can be inspected with a text editor.

The '.rpx' file is the report itself and the '.rps' file acts like a Windows application shortcut to launch the report editor and open the selected report for the current user of the Acumatica website.

When Acumatica installs the report editor in Windows it associates the '.rps' file type to the report editor. In Acumatica when you click 'Edit Report' the browser prompt the user to download the '.rps' file. When you open the '.rps' file, Windows recognize that it is associated with Acumatica report editor, launch the report editor and pass file path to the editor as a command line parameter.

The report editor then open and parse the '.rps' file and gets the necessary configuration info it needs to open the report from the website. Here is a sample content from an '.rps' file:

```
ServiceUrl|http://localhost/AcumaticaDemo/
ReportName|in615000.rpx
User|admin
```

Notice it contains only the necessary information to open a report from the website and it's not the report itself. When you save/export the report, you'll get an '.rpx' file that does contain the report. The '.rpx' is a standard XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Name="report1">
  <...></...>
</Report>
```

Comment: Thank you and I understand- but why does Acumatica sometime export the .rpx and other times open a report definitions window within the browser? I'm trying to edit this report in report designer, but I cannot locate the report name or export the .rpx.

Comment: If you have the '.rps' file, open it with a text editor, the report name is in there like the example in my answer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing 'open a report definitions window within the browser' ? It could be your browser that is not downloading the file and showing it's text content, that would be weird but could happen with some browser configurations.

Comment: If you mean the CS206000.aspx page, this is a configuration page for General Ledger reports. If you are redirected to that page, usually it's because it's required to save a configuration record there before you can use the report. This should be specific to report of that section. I wouldn't a report from another section like Inventory or Sales Order to redirect you there.

Comment: Screenshot posted. Yes- I'm getting the CS206000.aspx page, but would like to download the report for editing the design, parameters, etc... Could you please explain the last part regarding a configuration record? How am I supposed to edit the parameters / design of this report instead of getting to the CS206000.aspx page?

Comment: CS206000.aspx page is not a report, it's a configuration page, therefore you can't download that as a report. You have to open a report from the report section (bar graph icon in old UI) instead of a page from the configuration section (wrench icon in old UI).

Comment: It appears this was created using a configuration page and was added  to the sitemap under the report section. Am I able to "convert" this type of configuration into a report type?

Comment: Otherwise, how would I modify this configuration page to allow for a start period and end period. It appears that the report will pull year-to-date instead of one month regardless of the start period I select.

Comment: No absolutely not, this is apple and orange, a configuration page is not a report and will never be. First you need to identify which report you actually want to modify, not it's configuration page. For example "Balance - Comparative" that is GL report.

Comment: Though you are right that this report has a non standard behavior in opening a configuration page instead of the report editor.

Comment: The configuration page I'm referring to is for a GL report. It appears to simply be a UI for creating a report (ie. column sets and row sets). It even says "edit report" and "run report". It contains the exact layout I need. I just need to change the date range it produces and a bit of the design (ie. underline). I shouldn't have to rebuild a entire report from scratch, correct?

Comment: is there a way to locate the report name that this configuration is associated with? Then, I would be able to "open from server" using the report name.

Comment: The report in the Financial Statements of the General Section are the only one I know of with that behavior. They were likely not created with the possibility of customizing them in mind. Therefore I can't recommend any standard way to customize them, it would require studying in depth how they are built first.

Comment: They are not available in the list of customizable reports.

Comment: Any reasons the start date and end date parameters would not change the report? Is there another way to apply a date filter to this type of report?

Comment: At the moment I can't give advice as I think it would require lengthy research to understand how these specific reports work. Also they don't display their SQL request in the trace window for debugging as all the other standard reports do.

Comment: sorry for that, very busy today, hopefully someone else can chime in